# How long can a hand be submerged in freezing water?

Tags: human-biology, temperature

How long can one's hand be submerged in freezing (0°C) water before cell damage starts to occur? What causes the cell damage?

I know exposure to temperatures below freezing can quickly cause frostbite, and a decrease in core temperature can cause hypothermia, but I couldn't find any information on how temperatures just above freezing affect extremities.